# How do I disable wpautop for a specific block?

Tags: post-editor, block-editor, wp-autop

I've registered a custom editor block with Advanced Custom Fields (ACF), and am using `render_template` with a PHP template partial to display the block contents.

Inside the template is some HTML (`section` with a `figure` and an `a` inside it). When the block is called and the template generates the HTML, it's exactly as I author it, but when displayed on the front end, the `a` gets wrapped in a `p` tag, and a couple of `br` elements are added (I assume from `wpautop()`). This isn't happening on the editor side, just on the front end, which leads me to believe the block HTML is getting run through `the_content` or some other filters that run `wpautop()` before display.

I've tried running the block content through buffering, which breaks the editor but fixes the front end, and tried disabling `wpautop` from running in `the_content` filter, but have had mixed results.

So my question is how to tell WordPress that I like my markup, thank you very much, and please leave it alone for this specific block?

Here's a Gist of the block template: https://gist.github.com/morganestes/eca76cf8490f7b943d2f44c75674b648.

Answer (score 4):

@morgan-estes Great solution but it i think it should be better to **add_filter** in else so the next block or content gets filter with WPAUTOP

```
/**
 * Try to disable wpautop inside specific blocks.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/321662/26317
 *
 * @param string $block_content The HTML generated for the block.
 * @param array  $block         The block.
 */
add_filter( 'render_block', function ( $block_content, $block ) {
    if ( 'acf/featured-pages' === $block['blockName'] ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    } elseif ( ! has_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    }

    return $block_content;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found that I can use the `render_block` filter to disable `wpautop()` when a block gets rendered. It looks to me that this only affects the immediate block, as the filter gets re-enabled from `do_blocks()` calling `_restore_wpautop_hook()`. This lets me avoid using output buffering inside the block template, and moves the logic for filtering output out of the template and into a filter callback, where it makes more sense.

```
/**
 * Try to disable wpautop inside specific blocks.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/321662/26317
 *
 * @param string $block_content The HTML generated for the block.
 * @param array  $block         The block.
 */
add_filter( 'render_block', function ( $block_content, $block ) {
    if ( 'acf/featured-pages' === $block['blockName'] ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    }

    return $block_content;
}, 10, 2 );
```

I'm not sure of all the ramifications of this, but it's working to solve my immediate problem.

Comment: did you find any other solution to this problem ?

Comment: Not yet. That one's working for now and I haven't had time to dive deep to find out more.

Comment: It should be noted that `render_block()` was introduced with version 5.0.0 and is not available for version 4.x.x. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/render_block/